# missing menubar in android 2.3.5

Tags: android, menubar, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've created an application with a menubar, this menubar is shown in android >4.0 (galaxy III), but in android 2.3.5 (galaxy ace) it isn't show. What do I do for the menubar is shown correctly in both versions?
thank u.

Comment: What menubar? You mean the `ActionBar` or the `OptionsMenu`?

Comment: If you want ActionBar in 2.3.5 then you have to use SherlockActionBar library for backward portability. Be specific as mention by @SiddharthLele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean ActionBar, it's available only from Android 3.0: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

> You can control the behaviors and visibility of the action bar with the ActionBar APIs, which were added in Android 3.0 (API level 11).

If you want to add an ActionBar to your 2.3.5 application you should take a look at http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Regards

Comment: Thank u!!! I've used actionbarsherlock and the actinobar is shown correctly in Android 2.3.5